# Can Python 27 use twisted compiled by VC110 *not* VC90?

Tags: python, visual-c++, twisted

Our program is using Twisted-15.5.0-cp27-none-win32.whl from https://pypi.python.org/simple/twisted/

But two weeks ago, we don't know why the package was removed from the server.

I have to compile a twisted binaries from its source by ourselves. but the virtual machine we used (which are created dynamically) don't have VC90, it only has VC110.

As I know, the python 27 was compiled by VC90. I am not sure if using python 27 to call a twisted dll/component compiled by a VC110 can work fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use Unofficial Precompiled Python Packages (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted) if you don't want to compile on your own. Only downside is that they don't work for virtualenv.

Comment: But unfortunately, the unofficial packages you mentioned doesn't contain twisted 15.5. They only have 16.5 version.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realize that you needed a specific version. The only other alternative I can think of is using Anaconda and then installing packages via conda.